# Call to undefined function imagecreatefromwebp() on PHP 5.5.9

Tags: php, webp

I am getting this error on PHP 5.5.9, which is supposed to come with webp.

Am I doing something wrong or does webp need to be installed separately ?

> Call to undefined function imagecreatefromwebp()

Comment: What OS are you on and how are you calling the php script (command line interface or webserver? I'm on 5.5.4 on Windows with Apache 2 and the command works.

Comment: is your underlying `gd` version new enough to support that?

Comment: @user1781026 I'm on CentOS and it's a PHP script.

Comment: @MarcB I will have to check that, I didn't know it's related to `gd`

Comment: @MarcB I have GD 2.1.0, which should have webp.

Comment: ok. then did wherever php get compiled have that version? I'm not sure how "dynamic" PHP can be when it's being compiled as to which external lib functions it activates or not.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: same problem , need some solution.

Comment: I haven't solved it. Meanwhile I upgraded to PHP 7.x and it works.